# Find 'ordinary generating function': 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5....

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

This was on my midterm yesterday, but I couldn't solve it.

> Find an ordinary generating function:  1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5....

My answer was $(\frac{1}{1-x^2})^2$ because 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ... is $\frac{1}{1-x^2}$. (now I feel like it just doesn't make sense).

Can you find the ordinary generating function?

Comment: $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots$.  If you take the derivative of each side you get $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dots$.  This is different than $\frac{1}{1-(x^2)}=1+x^2+x^4+x^6+\dots$ which is what you wrote.

Comment: That being said, the answer will be $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}$ though it is not clear whether you got it correct for the correct reasons and you had typos, or if you made mistakes and only happened to get it correct by chance.

Comment: Why $(\frac{1}{1-x^2})^2$ isn't?

Comment: Oh am I right??? I got the right answer???? omg

Comment: I just wrote random answer. It was my instinct answer for that problem lol

Comment: I'm glad I got the right one

Comment: can please you elaborate how it's the right one for me?

Comment: By following my first comment, you have $\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}=1+2x+3x^2+4x^3+\dots$.  By letting $y=x^2$ and using the previous line with $y$ as the argument instead one has $\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}=\frac{1}{(1-y)^2}=1+2y+3y^2+4y^3+\dots=1+2x^2+3(x^2)^2+4(x^2)^3+\dots=1+0x+2x^2+0x^3+3x^4+0x^5+4x^6+\dots$

Comment: OHHHHHHHHH great!

Comment: Thanks a lot! If I were you, I would put your comment on answer though. Don't you want some credits for the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> We   obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{1+2x^2+3x^4+\cdots}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)x^{2n}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(x^2\right)^{n+1}\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty \left(x^2\right)^n\right)\\
> &=\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^2}-1\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}}
> \end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Observe that the sequence will correspond to the generating function
$$
(1+x^2+x^4+x^6\dotsb)+(x^2+x^4+x^6\dotsb)+(x^4+x^6+\dotsb)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2k}}{1-x^2}=\frac{1}{(1-x^2)^2}
$$
since
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^{2k}=\frac{1}{1-x^2}
$$
The manipulations above make sense as identities of analytic functions for $|x|<1$ or as identities of formal power series.